# Different titles for standard and wide tile (Metro-style app)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to set different text (name) for standard and wide tile? When I edit the package manifest, fill in the Short name and select wide or standard tile it seems to work only for that tile and the other one shows no text (name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Show Name combo allows to specify for which tile your Short Name will appear - it can be for both, none or only one of them. If you want to set a different text - you can embed the rasterized text in the tile image itself.